# Autoconf installed but doesn't work (ubuntu)

Tags: gnu, autoconf, automake

I'm trying to install GNU automake.  When running ./configure I get the following error message in the terminal:

```
    checking whether autoconf is installed... yes
    checking whether autoconf works... no
    configure: error: The installed version of autoconf does not work.
    Please check config.log for error messages before this one
```

Looking at the config.log I can't figure out where the problem is.  My guess it that it's with tex but I'm not sure what program that is even referring to.  I installed TexStudio and that didn't resolve it.
The log file is pasted below:

```
    configure:2784: checking for tex
    configure:2814: result: no
    configure:2822:  --version </dev/null
    ./configure: line 2823: --version: command not found
    configure:2825: $? = 127
    configure:2843: checking for yacc
    configure:2859: found /usr/local/bin/yacc
    configure:2870: result: yacc
    configure:2886: checking for lex
    configure:2916: result: no
    configure:2886: checking for flex
    configure:2902: found /usr/local/bin/flex
    configure:2913: result: flex
    configure:2934: checking whether autoconf is installed
    configure:2939: autoconf --version
    Autoconf version 2.10
    configure:2942: $? = 0
    configure:2950: result: yes
    configure:2957: checking whether autoconf works
    configure:2964: cd conftest && autoconf -o /dev/null conftest.ac
    Usage: autoconf [-h] [--help] [-m dir] [--macrodir=dir]
           [-l dir] [--localdir=dir] [--version] [template-file]
   configure:2967: $? = 1
   configure:2976: result: no
   configure:2979: error: The installed version of autoconf does not work.
          Please check config.log for error messages before this one.
```

Answer (score 1):

As Diego said, if you install `autoconf` from the repositories it will install the version 2.68. For some reason, you might have the version 2.13 installed.

If it is the case remove the old version and install the default version:

`sudo apt-get remove autoconf2.13 && sudo apt-get install autoconf`

Answer (score 0):

Autoconf 2.1 is *very* old and has significantly different semantics from the current version (2.69, called the "2.5 series".)

Ubuntu appears to have [separate packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/autoconf) for autoconf 2.1 and 2.6x but I'm not sure how they select across the two.